# Mapreduce job outputs error "JobTracker is not yet RUNNING"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have just installed hadoop (single-node) and I'm trying to run a simple test problem. My code runs fine in Java, but when I try to run it in hadoop, I get the following error:

```
$hadoop jar build/libs/mapreduce-hello-0.1.0.jar mapreduce.AggregateJob data output

14/05/15 15:37:30 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:pmedilla cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTrackerNotYetInitializedException: JobTracker is not yet RUNNING
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.checkJobTrackerState(JobTracker.java:5199)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getNewJobId(JobTracker.java:3543)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTrackerNotYetInitializedException: JobTracker is not yet RUNNING
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.checkJobTrackerState(JobTracker.java:5199)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getNewJobId(JobTracker.java:3543)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy2.getNewJobId(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy2.getNewJobId(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:944)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
at mapreduce.AggregateJob.run(AggregateJob.java:32)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
at mapreduce.AggregateJob.main(AggregateJob.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

When I run jps, I get:

```
32643 Jps
32041 
31288 SecondaryNameNode
31445 TaskTracker
31353 JobTracker
31106 NameNode
```

I notice that the data node is missing (or blank). Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you configured [mapred-site.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml) to point to the jobtracker ? Have a look at this mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address

Comment: @Sudarshan My mapred.jon.tracker is set to the local host, since this is a very simple test job. The xlm file looks like this: <configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>localhost:9010</value>
</property>
</configuration>

Comment: If I do that, it tries unsuccesfully to connect to the server: 14/05/15 17:23:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: The last comment was a mess up, apologies. I am thinking if localhost:9010 should be localhost:9000. Not a 100% sure though